# PHP include top file and bottom file containing ifelse curly braces

Tags: include, if-statement, braces

How can I include_once a php file at the top that contains an if statement with an open curly brace,

And then include a file at the bottom that contains the closing curly brace to that if statement with more if statements preceding it?

```
<?php include_once('includes/authtop.php');?>

<div id="mydiv">
// stuff here
</div>

<?php include_once('includes/authbottom.php');?>

**Note**: authbottom.php contains several ifelse statements and displays data accordingly.
```

I need to do this to have more clean and organized code but when I move the code into the includes I get an error, it's as if the rendered page does not recognize the curly braces for open close?

If its to do with a function or function/class could someone please give me an example.

This is the top file: authtop.php

```
if( $loggedin ) { 

if( $accessLevel == 0  ) {
```

This is the bottom file: authbottom.php

```
} elseif() {

// do this

} elseif() {

// do this 

} elseif() {

// do this 

} else {

// do this

}
```

Comment: Oh yes and the error i get is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in ( On the last line of the first include where the curly brace is )

Answer (score 0):

You should not be including files to handle conditions in that manner. It's messy and error prone; as you have discovered.

Instead, refactor your code.

Here is an example of that...

```
function someFunc() {
   if( $loggedin ) { 

      if( $accessLevel == 0  ) {

        return TRUE;

      } elseif() {

      // do this

      } elseif() {

      // do this 

      } elseif() {

      // do this 

      } else {

      // do this

      }
}



if (someFunc()) {
    // stuff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks alex, that seems cleare. But does that mean all my html has to go between those if statements? i was hoping my first if result which has the most code could be kept on the main file while the others which only contain smalle bits of code could go in the final if statements

Comment: with return TRUE, can i somehow use that?

Comment: @jonnypixel: That in the condition at the bottom of my example will mean the code in the braces will be executed.

Comment: can i kep the main body for code on my initial page? is there a way of returning the first result so that it displays the first block of code from another file?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a switch

```
include('authtop.php);

switch($accesslevel) {
  default:
  case 0: include('filepath.php'); break;
  case 1: include('filepath.php'); break;
  case 2: include('filepath.php'); break;
  case 3: include('filepath.php'); break;
  case 4: include('filepath.php'); break;
}

include('authbottom.php');
```

or....

```
switch($accesslevel) {
  default:
  case 0: 
       if($paid==0) { $pd='THANKS'; } else { $pd='DONATE!'; }
       $lvl = 'Guest';
       /* whatever you need to include for level 0 here */
       break;
  case 1:
       if($paid==0) { $pd='THANKS'; } else { $pd='DONATE!'; }
       $lvl = 'User';
       /* whatever you need to include for level 1 here */
       break;
  case 2:
       if($paid==0) { $pd='THANKS'; } else { $pd='DONATE!'; }
       $lvl = 'Moderator';
       /* whatever you need to include for level 2 here */
       break;
  case 3:
       if($paid==0) { $pd='THANKS'; } else { $pd='DONATE!'; }
       $lvl = 'Super Moderator';
       /* whatever you need to include for level 3 here */
       break;
  case 4: 
       if($paid==0) { $pd='THANKS'; } else { $pd='DONATE!'; }
       $lvl = 'Admin';
       /* whatever you need to include for level 4 here */
       break;
}


echo '
<div class="myDiv">'.$pd.'</div>
<div class="myDiv2">'.$lvl.'</div> ';
```

The HTML will show whatever the $pd variable has been set at according to the switch.

And it's best to set up the include so they are self contained without any open braces or brackets.

Comment: thanks scott, the thing is though that they have to have the braces. Your method looks like it will work but alex's method looks like the more organised way to go. I just have tried the code from alex and cant seem to get my head around it. Will try your example as well. How would i do the curl;y brace thing then?

Comment: You don't need anymore if/else statements. A switch is basically a more organized, multi-level, if/else statement. I prefer switches to long if/ifelse/ifelse/ifelse/else statements. I've edited above to show you where to put user level specific content. And it would be assumed if the user is not logged in, the access level would be 0. You really shouldn't need a separate variable for logged in.

Comment: why cant i include a php file at the top that contains an open curly at the end of it and then include a php file at the bottom that contains a closing curly for the open curly? the thing is that im not switching through various levels of permisison but my other if statemnts contain an extra condition with them. eg: if accesslevel = 1 && paid == 0 and then if accesslevel = 1 && paid = 1 etc...

Comment: oh, i didnt know you could do that.. thanks i will play with this and come back and rate. Cheers for the examples scott.

Comment: Sounds like you may be intermingling the php functions with HTML which can make things more complicated. Use php to set variables, then simply use HTML to show those variables.